# trying to import firebase but it shows some kind of syntax error

Tags: python, firebase

```
 import firebase from firebase
```

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax [Finished in 0.087]

I am unable to import firebase for python.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying

`import firebase from firebase`

This is wrong. The correct way to import is

`from firebase import firebase`

Comment: still didn't work  it shows :from firebase import firebase
  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\firebase.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .firebase_token_generator import FirebaseTokenGenerator
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
[Finished in 0.119s]

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do that is:

```
import pyrebase 
config = {
  "apikey":"apikey"
   .............
}
firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
```

Comment: i tried this one but it says : import pyrebase
  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\pyrebase.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
[Finished in 0.095s]

Comment: You need to have pyrebase module. try this:                                        pip3 install pyrebase

Comment: import pyrebase
  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\pyrebase\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .pyrebase import initialize_app
  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\pyrebase\pyrebase.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\requests\__init__.py", line 46, in <module>
    from .exceptions import RequestsDependencyWarning
  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\requests\exceptions.py", line 9, in <module>
    from urllib3.exceptions import HTTPError as BaseHTTPError
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib3.exceptions'

Comment: problem is still there  .

Comment: File "C:\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\pyrebase\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .pyrebase import initialize_app
  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\pyrebase\pyrebase\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .pyrebase import initialize_app
  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\pyrebase\pyrebase\pyrebase.py", line 2, in <module>
    from requests import Session
ImportError: cannot import name 'Session'